# ¿Cómo puedo crear una funcion que solo cuente los valores negativos del vector que le esté pasando?

Tags: r

Me gustaría que la respuesta me arroje los valores negativos de, por ejemplo, el vector `vectorRandom <- (-4:4)`. Solo que no se como acomodar la función.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uno de los mecanismos clásicos para seleccionar o filtrar valores de un vector u otros tipos de objetos, es el de la selección lógica, es decir condicionar está a partir de otro vector de valores lógicos dónde `TRUE` significa, "quiero este elemento":

```
> vectorRandom
[1] -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4

> vectorRandom >= 0
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

> vectorRandom[vectorRandom >= 0]
[1] 0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Se entiende perfecto.